# Irreducible surfaces of $x^3+y^3+z^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ the fermat cubic. Let $f=x$ I have to find $Spec(R_x)$. So I have to find all prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ that contain $(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ and not contain x. I have not strategy to do it. I know that into the fermat cubic there are 27 lines. If I cut it with $x=0$, remain 26 lines? (or 24...) But I looking for a method in order to classify the others...

Comment: Maybe $R[x^{-1}] \cong \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}][u,v]/(1+u^3+v^3)$ (with $u=y/x$, $v=z/x$) helps.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Can you give me some references in order to do it?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}$ solves $x^3+y^3+z^3$ (when $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$), so also $(t,bt,ct)$ solve it. Then we have infinite lines corrisponding to the ideals $(by-x,cz-x)$. But how can I prove that exist $\alpha(x,y,z), \beta(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ such that $(x^3+y^3+z^3=\alpha(x,y,z)(by-x)+\beta(x,y,z)(cz-x)$?